# OSMDroid zip - how to add custom maps?

Tags: android, zip, osmdroid

I am using OSMdroid's MapView and I am planning to add custom maps. I cannot convert them via MOBAC, I need to find out the format preferrences and characteristics. Have you seem some information about it? I have been looking for it for weeks but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean the tile format?  I belive [this](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) is a good reference.

Comment: That is a VERY good reference. I've been looking for a correlation between file number and lat/lon for a while now without success. Thanks a lot.