# Offline World Satellite Map Without Labels(Android)

Tags: android, dictionary, offline, satellite

I want to include a MapView in my Application. I have been playing around with the Google Api a bit and it worked quite well.

But now I want to have a map completely offline.
I know there are a lot of possibilities to do this.

The problem is that I would like to have a world map without any labels such as country names, state names, city names and so on. 
I just want a map with country borders. It should be possible to zoom in and out and to set markers at specific locations. It should also be possible to tap somewhere in the screen and to get the coordinates in a specific format (e.g WGS84).
Also it would be pretty nice if it would be a satellite overview or something like the mapquest view on OpenStreetMap.org .

I know that there are things like Osmdroid or Mapsforge. But I havent seen a possibility to disable all the (for me) unnecessary labels yet. 
Correct me if i am wrong :)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094076/osmdroid-zip-how-to-add-custom-maps - Google`s `MapView` will not work for that since you can't control the map data. If osmdroid does not work for you, you'll probably have to implement your own map viewer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check your and Luis' suggestion and see what I can get t work.

Answer (score 1):

In `mapforges` you can set label text size. I've never tried to set it to `0` to see if they disapear.

If not, as source code is available in http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/, you can override the label drawing and recompile it.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I will check out both and see what works for me.

Unfortunately I have created my Google-Mail Account after I have been signing up here with my Google Account. Now I had to create a new account here...